can TypeORM 0.3.x be used in a project using TypeScript 5 style decorators?
I am trying to use TypeORM, but it seems to require these settings in tsconfig.json
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,

I also have started creating my own TypeScript 5.x decorators. The issue is that enabling the above settings for TypeORM creates errors with my decorator:
Decorator function return type '(this: any, ...args: any[]) => any' is not assignable to type 'void | TypedPropertyDescriptor<(a: number, b: number) => number>'.ts(1270)
Is there any way for these two style to coexist?
